# how to show data inside td using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to show a table inside a td with an on click function. But it shows the tables in the complete column with the on click function .How to make it only show the table of the same td on which click function is performed?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checklistbox").hide();
  $("#row_list").hide();

  $("#checklist").click(function() {
    $("#checklistbox").show();
  });

  $("input").click(function() {
    $("#checklistbox").hide();
  });


});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nameinitials").each(function() {
    $(".table-responsive").hide();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".val_resp").click(function() {
    $("#val_resp").each(function() {
      $(".table-responsive").show();
    });
  });


  $("input").click(function() {
    $("#val_resp").each(function() {
      $(".table-responsive").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: my all rows has same input and i want to show the value of the only td on which click is performed.now on click it make visible table inside all td which have same table

Comment: Where is your markup?

Comment: `$("#val_resp").each()` doesn't make sense. There can only be one element with that ID, why do you need a loop?

Comment: because i call same data in each row.of table with while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM traversal functions relative to `$(this)`

```
$(".val_resp").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("td").find(".table_responsive").show();
});
```

Comment: This is just an example. Since you didn't post your HTML, I don't know the exact relationship between the element you click on and where the table you want to show is. You should adapt it to your needs. See https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ for all the jQuery traversal functions.